# How do I open Chrome with proxy for a specified profile on mac?

Tags: terminal, google-chrome

I'm trying to open Chrome with proxy for a specified profile on mac from terminal on mac, something like

[image]

where "Profile 1" accesses sites via proxy while other Profiles doesn't.

`127.0.0.1:1081` is my local proxy which is working well.

I tried this command

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Profile 1" --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:1081
```

but it doesn't work at all.

I also tried this but get no luck.

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Profile 1" --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

Could someone give me a hint?

PS: This job doesn't have to be done from terminal, although I just tried some suggestions involved terminal. If it's unfeasible with terminal, I'm willing to try other way, e.g. chrome extensions.